# Adding two lists together with map

Tags: list, haskell, dictionary

So I'm trying to write some minimal code to put two lists of strings together, and to do this I thought it was best to use the haskell map function.

Essentially I want to be able to do adders ["1","2"] ["3","4"] = ["1","2","3","4"]

So I have a function called adder, which takes a list, then adds a string to that list and returns the new list. Then I have a function called adders which replicates the adder function, but adds a list of strings instead of just one string, however at the moment it produces multiple lists instead of one list.

I thought

```
adder :: [String] -> String -> [String]
adder y x = y ++ [x]

adders y x = map (adder y) x
```

would work, but this just gives a list of two lists
[["1","2","3"],[["1","2","4"]]

How is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Could you please format your post correctly? What should `adders` do? What do you expect `adder` to do? And why don't you use `adders y x = y ++ x`?

Comment: `["1","2"] ["3","4"] = ["1","2","3","4"]` would have the type `[String] -> [String] -> [String]`

Comment: @Zeta that final point is what I was trying to achieve, sorry I didn't realize I could do that.

Comment: ...why, if you use the standard operator `++` anyway, do you even define `adders` at all? Whereever you use `adders`, you could simply call `++` directly. Or, you could define `adders = (++)`. — Do you perhaps mean to ask how to define this _without_ a library operator, only in terms of the plain list constructor (`:`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought it was best to use the haskell map function

No. `map f` applies `f` to every element of your list. But you don't want to change the elements at all, you want to change the list itself. That, however, is out of scope of the things that are possible with `map`. `map` cannot add more elements, neither can it remove some.

If you want to concatenate two lists, simply use `++`:

```
adders :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
adders x y = x ++ y
```